# Android CameraX crahses on second launch of the intent on physical devices but it works fine on the emulator. What could be the issues here?

Tags: java, android, android-camerax

I was implementing CameraX into camera class and cameraAcvitity class such as

This is the activity launches the cameraX

```
/**
 * Represents a custom camera activity. This activity allows the user to capture images using the device's camera.
 */
public class CustomCameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CustomCamera customCamera;
    private PreviewView previewView;
    private ImageView capturedImage;
    private Button okButton;
    private Button reTryButton;

    private ImageButton captureBtn,flipCameraBtn;

    // Asking for Permission to capture Camera
    private final ActivityResultLauncher<String> activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), result -> {
        if (result) {
            startCamera();
        }
    });


    /**
     * Initializes the activity, sets up the camera and the buttons.
     *
     * @param savedInstanceState If the activity is being re-initialized after previously being shut down, this contains the data it most recently supplied in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle). Otherwise, it is null.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_camera);
        int cameraFacing = CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK;
        previewView = findViewById(R.id.customPreview);
        captureBtn = findViewById(R.id.capture_btn);
        okButton = findViewById(R.id.ok_btn);
        reTryButton = findViewById(R.id.retry_btn);
        capturedImage = findViewById(R.id.capture_image);
        flipCameraBtn = findViewById(R.id.flipCamera_btn);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(CustomCameraActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            activityResultLauncher.launch(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        } else {
            startCamera();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Starts the camera and sets up the capture and flip camera buttons.
     */
    private void startCamera() {
        // Initialize your custom CameraX instance
        previewView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        captureBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        flipCameraBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        okButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        reTryButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        capturedImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        customCamera = new CustomCamera(previewView);
        customCamera.startCamera(this);
        captureBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> captureImage());
        flipCameraBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            customCamera.flipCamera();
            customCamera.startCamera(CustomCameraActivity.this);
        });

    }

    /**
     *
     * Starts the camera and sets up the capture and flip camera buttons.
     *
     */
    private void captureImage() {
        final File photoFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        //File photoFile = createImageFile();

        ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback callback = new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback() {
               /**
                 * Sets buttons to visible or invisible for an image
                 * @param outputFileResults the image that was taken
                 */

            @Override
            public void onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    Uri imageUri = outputFileResults.getSavedUri();
                    previewView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    captureBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    flipCameraBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    okButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    reTryButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    capturedImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    capturedImage.setImageURI(imageUri);
                    okButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                        Toast.makeText(CustomCameraActivity.this, "ImageSaved: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Uri imageUri1 = outputFileResults.getSavedUri();
                        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                        resultIntent.setData(imageUri1);
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
                        finish();
                    });
                    reTryButton.setOnClickListener(v -> startCamera());
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException exception) {
                // Handle error
                runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(CustomCameraActivity.this, "Image saved at: " + photoFile.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());

            }
        };
        customCamera.captureImage(photoFile, callback);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param height the height of the screen on camera(Y axis)
     * @param width the width of the screen on camera(X axis)
     * @return AspectRatio that the ratio of camera in scale
     */
    private int aspectRatio(int width, int height) {
        double previewRatio = (double) Math.max(width, height) / Math.min(width, height);
        if (Math.abs(previewRatio - 4.0 / 3.0) <= Math.abs(previewRatio - 16.0 / 9.0)) {
            return AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3;
        }
        return AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9;
    }

    /**
     * Creates an image file with a unique name in the "CameraXImages" directory.
     *
     * @return The created image file.
     */
    private File createImageFile() {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "CameraXImages");

        try {
            File image = File.createTempFile(
                    imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                    ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                    storageDir      /* directory */
            );

            String currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
            return image;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

    }


}
```

The customCameraX class is:

```
/**
 * Represents a custom camera that can capture images and switch between front and back camera.
 */
public class CustomCamera {

    private PreviewView previewView;
    private ImageCapture imageCapture;
    private Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    private int cameraFacing;
    ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider;

    /**
     * Constructs a new CustomCamera with the given PreviewView.
     *
     * @param previewView The PreviewView where the camera preview will be displayed.
     */
    public CustomCamera(PreviewView previewView) {
        this.previewView = previewView;
        this.cameraFacing=CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK;
    }

    /**
     * Flips the camera from back to front, or from front to back.
     */
    public void flipCamera(){
        if(this.cameraFacing == CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK){
            this.cameraFacing= CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT;
        }
        else{
            this.cameraFacing=CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Starts the camera and binds it to the lifecycle of the given LifecycleOwner.
     *
     * @param lifecycleOwner The LifecycleOwner that the camera is bound to.
     */
    public void startCamera(LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner) {
        ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(previewView.getContext());

        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {
            try {
                 cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();

                // Set up the camera use cases
                bindCameraUseCases(lifecycleOwner);
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(previewView.getContext()));
    }

    /**
     * Binds the camera use cases to the given ProcessCameraProvider and LifecycleOwner.
     * @param lifecycleOwner The LifecycleOwner that the camera use cases are bound to.
     */
    private void bindCameraUseCases(LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner) {
        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();
        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(cameraFacing)
                .build();

        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());

        imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
                .setTargetRotation(previewView.getDisplay().getRotation())
                .build();

        cameraProvider.unbindAll();
        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture);
    }
    /**
     * Captures an image and saves it to the given file. If the image capture is not initialized, this method does nothing.
     *
     * @param outputFile The file where the image will be saved.
     * @param callback The callback that will be invoked after the image has been captured.
     */
    public void captureImage(File outputFile, ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback callback) {
        if (imageCapture != null) {
            ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions outputOptions = new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(outputFile).build();
            imageCapture.takePicture(outputOptions, executor, callback);
        }
    }
}
```

I am starting this activity as `pictureActivityResultLauncher.launch(cameraIntent)` and recieve the data as

```
  ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> pictureActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        // There are no request codes
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                        ......
                      }
            });
```

When I run on the android emulator on android studio, it worked fine. However when I connect to the actual devices and first picture works fine but it crashes on the second launch of camera intent.
I tried to solve it by creating releasing methods that unbinds the cameraProvider in camera class and release it when the the camera activity closes but it does not make any changes. I am still quite not sure why it crashes on physical devices only not in the emulator the log says

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.team29project, PID: 29992
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.Display.getRotation()' on a null object reference
> at com.example.team29project.Model.CustomCamera.bindCameraUseCases(CustomCamera.java:85)
> at com.example.team29project.Model.CustomCamera.lambda$startCamera$0$com-example-team29project-Model-CustomCamera(CustomCamera.java:65)
> at com.example.team29project.Model.CustomCamera$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:6)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8762)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)

Edit: I figured it out. It was the setTargetRotation from bindCamerauUseCases methods. I removed it and it works fine now.

Comment: Can you share the crash log with us?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the display rotation before the display is ready. Usually, you don't even have to set the target rotation. If absent, CameraX will use the default display's rotation.

Otherwise, there are 2 ways that you can try:

1. You can handle it yourself by waiting until the display is ready, or
2. You can use the high level API [CameraController](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/CameraController) which handles the rotation for you.